# CSS changes not taking effect in customized styles folder

Tags: theming

I am trying to size the banner in a Jackson theme on my site to fit to the 960px wrapper size have in customized folder in sites/all/themes/mytheme/styles/mytheme.css but no matter what I do the length won't change, only the height which makes no sense at all.

I have tried flushing the cache several times but still no changes take effect.

The code in jackson styles.css is

```
#banner-wrap {
   background: transparent url(../images/main-sprite.png) repeat-x scroll center -90px;
   height: 133px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I have successfully changed the height but if I change width from 100% to 960px it does nothing.

Comment: Try changing the CSS using Firebug, Chrome developer tools, etc.  If it doesn't take effect there, either, you know your CSS is wrong.

Comment: You have to change it in Jackson theme style.css  not in separate folder style.css

Comment: Either do what Bala said or try and use !important when you change the width. 

  .banner-wrap {
    like you have it now ....;
    width:960px !important;
  }

Comment: It is working now - I realized the image was what needed to be changed to be correct dimension for 100% width. BUT NOW the banner image not showing up on forum page but will ask that question separately. Thanks to all.

Comment: So much confusion on CSS — based on questions to SE — can be avoided with a basic CSS understanding of inheritance, precedence and specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes to the style.css file which is in Jackson theme folder. Not under mytheme

1. Use

   ```
   #banner-wrap {
   background: transparent url(../images/main-sprite.png) repeat-x scroll center -90px !important;
   height: 133px !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   }
   ```
2. Add this in to `style.css` file
3. Flush the cache once.

Comment: actually I now have it working - my image was wrong dimension! BUT anyway I added that exact code in mytheme folder copied from jackson style.css.

Comment: Thank you but I think it is important to add to mytheme because I changed the height dimension.

Comment: so your image path should be something like: `../../images/main-sprite.png`

Comment: I just reloaded the image with correct dimension and placed in sites/default/files and chmoded to 700 and apache chown and now it works except on forum pg and one of views result pg.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the 100% width in Jackson theme and make sure the image file is same width as the container.

Answer (score 0):

As you theme's css file uses the image. It is better you should put the image in the theme's images folder itself so that you can give corresponding path such as `../images/main-sprite.png`. If you place image file under `sites/default/files` folder then relative path will change every-time you visit different URL. That is the reason why you are not able to get the image on view and forum page. Image path should be accessible from css folder so better to keep the image under `jackson_theme_path/images/main-sprite.png`. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting- I will see if you are right!